# How to start tmux session on the server by ssh and execute script in the session

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I have a program on the server, which execution should be initiated from the client by bash script with the use of ssh. Moreover, this script should open the tmux session on the server, run the program with some argument and terminate the session after program return.

I tried several solutions, but no one has been successful.

1)

```
#! /bin/bash
 
argument='12345678'
ssh user@host << EOF
   tmux new-session -t session1
   ./program $argument
   tmux kill-session -t session1
EOF
```

The program executes on the server, but without tmux session.

Output: "open terminal failed: not a terminal"

2)

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh user@host -t 'tmux new-session -t session1'
```

As minimum, this command open the session (actually don't know what is the construction `ssh user@host -t '...'` and how it works. If someone explains, I will be grateful) and I can type commands manually. But I don't know how to make server run my program using the script as I plan. Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to create a "detached" tmux session, then use `tmux send-keys` to send command instructions to the session. Also, I would use the full path to `program`. E.g. something like this

```bash
ssh user@host << EOF
   tmux new-session -t session1 -d
   tmux send-keys -t session1 "/path/to/the/program $argument" C-m
   tmux kill-session -t session1
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start a new `tmux` session in detached mode and then send commands with `tmux send-keys` command:

#! /bin/bash

```
argument='12345678'
ssh user@host << EOF
   tmux new-session -t session1 -d
   tmux send-keys -t session1:1 "./program $argument && tmux -d" ENTER
EOF
```

Answer (score -1):

Tell `tmux` to run the program for you.

```
ssh user@host "tmux new-session -t session1 './program \"$argument\"'"
```

This runs `program` *instead* of a shell in the (only) window of the new session. When the program exits, the window is closed and along with it the session ends. (Quoting can get a bit hairy, so I'm calling that out-of-scope for this question.)

Comment: Dear chepner, I've tried your variant on the simple example.

`argument='exmpl'`

`ssh user@host "tmux new-session -t session1 'touch \"$argument\"'" `

File exmpl hasn't been created... Client's terminal give me output: "command or window name given with target"

Comment: I have the same output as @EGOR_MIPT, and no tmux session is created :(

Comment: A one-liner that worked for me is:
`ssh user@host "tmux new-session -d -t 'myTempSession' 'cd dir; python3 ./src/main.py'` (src: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335087/how-to-execute-code-in-a-new-tmux-session-from-within-current-session). The one issue is that the tmux session is a temporary one.